# Call (or pass parameter to) .aspx page from outlook

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, outlook, sendmail

I am new to asp.net.

I have a button present in outlook mail and when a use click on that button, then I want to call (or pass parameter to) .aspx page from outlook.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Show some code you done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't do that. Outlook will not run any scripts or process any form code in an HTML message. The links will work, but they will be opened in a separate browser window outside Outlook.
Or did you mean you wrote an Outlook addin and added your custom button to an Outlook inspector?

Comment: I want to add a button in outlook mail and when the use click on button, some parameters need to pass to a URL and then that URL page will get execute. How I can do that. Any help will be useful.

Comment: Add it where? The HTML message body? Or the toolbar/ribbon in an Outlook inspector?

Comment: I want to add in the HTML message body.

Comment: Can't do that. OUtlook will not run any scripts or process any HTML forms in messages for the security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

```
Process.Start("http://example.com?Page.aspxparam=value");
```

will open default browser by url given and will pass param=value to the page.

Comment: @MaheshAlle: This is a C# code to write in your addin or where do you write in C#?

Comment: Yes I got you point, but I don't want to open any page from outlook. How I can do that. Any help.